# Building a static array at compile time

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I have a few large static arrays that are used in a resource constrained embedded system (small microcontroller, bare metal). These are occasionally added to over the course of the project, but all follow that same mathematical formula for population. I could just make a Python script to generate a new header with the needed arrays before compilation, but it would be nicer to have it happen in the pre-processor like you might do with template meta-programming in C++. Is there any relatively easy way to do this in C? I've seen ways to get control structures like `while` loops using just the pre-processor, but that seems a bit unnatural to me.

Here is an example of once such map, an approximation to `arctan`, in Python, where the parameter `a` is used to determine the length and values of the array, and is currently run at a variety of values from about 100 to about 2^14:

```
def make_array(a):
    output = []
    for x in range(a):
        val = round(a * ((x / a)**2 / (2 * (x / a)**2 - 2 * (x / a) + 1)))
        output.append(val)
    return output
```

Comment: We'd need to know what the formulas look like, can you provide regular runtime code to populate the arrays, either in C or Python?

Comment: Although it does depend somewhat on the details of what you are trying to do, chances are that no, there is *not* any "relatively easy" way to do this via the preprocessor.  At minimum, your proposed code generator is almost certain to be much easier to write, read, debug, and maintain.

Comment: The C preprocessor is a preprocessor. Python, when used this way, is a preprocessor. There is no good reason to prefer the C preprocessor except that it is built in. Use the one that suits the task better

Comment: Can you please post some code example even if it's just pseudo code?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with this in general, but it adds more overhead to each build, and a dev working on this after I'm long gone (or a future me) might not be aware of this step. It would be more natural if the "typical" build process took care of it without the extra steps. I can document it and create build scripts and all, but that doesn't mean the new guy will follow them correctly. I can't guarantee everything will always go smoothly, but adding extra steps, if they are unnecessary, increases the likelihood of problems.

Comment: Did you try macros with a call hierarchy on a base of powers of two or some other appropriate value? Well, I'm aware that this sounds blury, so please [edit] your question and provide a simple example of a table. How many entries are in the arrays? -- I did this some years ago for CRC tables, just with some lines of preprocessor magic - but **it was barely readable**. And because one of the compilers to use had a hard limit on preprocessed lines, I abused enums to spread the burden between preprocessor and compiler. It worked, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Do you have a makefile?  You can add running this script to it.

Comment: @4386427 I largely agree, but in this case, it is extremely unlikely that whoever may work on the codebase next will have any experience at all with the toolchain, and likely little experience with C. I often have to prioritize these types of constraints, which usually means attempting to minimize deviation from what might be found in the most basic tutorials and examples. In this case I think that Python is the best answer, but if someone here knew something that would minimize the build process, and add less complexity than a Python script, I wanted to hear about it.

Comment: @4386427 Well, as little as it matters that you have a perfect global understanding in order to respond (or not respond) to a question with local scope, it will matter (at least) when someone who doesn't know what they are doing decides to build the project, but tries to use a newer version of the build tools that will break the existing workflow, creating a need to revise the build process. Again, it's not salient here, but this has happened before, and it's not entirely uncommon in embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any relatively easy way to do this in C?

No.

Stick to a Python script and incorporate it inside your build system. It is normal to generate C code using other scripts. This will be strongly relatively easier than a million lines of C code.

Take a look at M4 or Jinja2 (or PHP) - these macro processors allow sharing code with C source in the same file.